# Port 80 Security Risk

Tags: security, port-forwarding, internet-security

Let's say I make a simple web page that just says "hello world" with no buttons, no forms, nothing but plain text. Now I port forward the private IP address of this computer to my router sending through port 80 of the server so that now a user can just type in my public IP address anywhere in the world and read my "hello world". What are the security risks? I know of the many security risks in web programming such as Inclusion Attacks, SQL Injection Attacks, Click-Jacking, and target="_blank" Attacks, but this hello world site is just plain text. What then are the risks?

Comment: The risk is a security bug of the http daemon itself.

Comment: You are now susceptible to a Denial of Service (DoS) attack; your system could be overwhelmed with web page requests and crash.

Comment: @Hydraxan14 You can DOS any open port.

Comment: @Ramhound ...so?  He has only indicated that port 80 has been forwarded.  The rest of the ports are still safely behind NAT.  A DoS on any other port would be an attack upon his router, which would have been possible before setting up this web server.

Comment: To perform a DoS attack against a service, you need to be able to connect to the service. To just overwhelm the entire connection, there is really no need for that. As such, that point is pretty much moot. You can easily saturate most home Internet connections.

Answer (score 2):

If you listen/bind on port 80, then you need capability CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE ( to bind to port <1024 ). Traditionally this is only allowed to user root/admin (**here is a big security problem**).

However on modern Linux you can run it as an unprivileged, special purpose, user and give the server just this capability.

You could also set up the firewall to restrict number of connections/second. (to reduce DOS).

You could on Linux put it in a container (e.g. docker), to restrict what system resources it uses.

Comment: Dropping privileges after binding to the privileged port has long since been common practice. So that’s not really an issue.

Comment: @DanielB capabilities are new. You no longer need the all powerful root. So use capabilities, and drop them when no longer needed.

Comment: Sort-of new, yes. My point was that, even without capabilities, you can drop all privileges not required for normal operation (ie. anything *but* binding to the port) and only after that accept connections. Of course, *with* capabilities, you can *start* with a lot less privileges, further reducing attack surface.

Answer (score 0):

By setting up that forward you enabled internet hosts to directly connect to your machine.

As such you increased your direct attack surface by whatever the web server has to offer. If there is a bug that could be triggered by a simple request that bug is no exposed to direct attacks. In addition you would supply additional information about your system to possible attackers depending on the information that is being send by the web server in other headers.

An example of such information could be the `Server` header which would include information about the used server software or the `X-Powered-By` header which could include information about the used PHP version and possible OS.